# Office 365 Exchange automatically delete deleted items

Tags: microsoft-office-365, mailbox, rules, exchangeonline

How would I automatically delete email older than one week in deleted items folder?  I have access to the mailbox through OWA.  Would this be done using a Rule, Retention Policy or Archiving?  Setting up a Rule or Retention Policy appears to only work on the inbox.  No archiving option when I right click on the Deleted Items folder.

All mailboxes are managed through exchange in Office 365 Admin Center.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use retention policy to achieve your needs. RPT(Retention policy tag) is created for default folders, you can create a tag applied to delete items folder, and then link to a retention policy. Details see: [Default folders that support Retention Policy Tags](https://docs.microsoft.com/zh-cn/exchange/security-and-compliance/messaging-records-management/default-folders)

Comment: Thanks Niko.  I created a Retention Tag and assigned it ti a Retention Policy.  The following message appears when I assign this Retention Policy to a user:

Warning: Please update UseDatabaseQuotaDefaults to false in order to mailbox quotas to apply.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I set UseDatabaseQuotaDefaults to false using powershell.